# How to use ElasticSearch prefix query matching words of minimum size i chose

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search using **prefix** query. I am getting results but its kind of not exactly what i want. Let me explain it in following example. Suppose i search using prefix as

```
"query": 
{
   "prefix" : { "title" : "o" }
}
```

I get results like following

1. something **of** something
2. something **or** something
3. something **original**

Out of above 3 only last one is of my interest. So I wonder is there any way I can tell elasticsearch that please return only the results where prefix matched for words (or inverted indices to be more specific) which are greater than or equal to length (say) 5.

Comment: may be post the `mapping` as well as a sample document? to see what type of content you have in the field and from the mapping to see what type of analyzer you use

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in prefix query **to return only the results where prefix matched for words (or inverted indices to be more specific) which are greater than or equal to length (say) 5**.  I even tried the [index-prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-prefixes.html) which would create separate tokens in your inverted index but didn't solve the issue.

Then, I created a custom analyzer based on [edge-ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer where I specified the min gram length of 5 and then applied the same on the title field. this way your `original` text would be tokenized in below manner:

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "origi",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "origin",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        },
        {
            "token": "origina",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 2
        },
        {
            "token": "original",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 8,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

while for `or`, `of`, `orig` it would not create any tokens at all, as min gram is specified in the tokenizer as 5. **And now your same prefix query would fetch just the expected document.**

I have verified this in my local and [this](https://www.getpostman.com/collections/2098eb05863cb8f8e419) is the postman collection link of index-mapping, your sample documents, search and analyze query for you to better understand this.

Comment: Instead of edge ngram you can use length token filter with min size 5 which will avoid creating unnecessary tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [length filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html) with `min: 5` parameter to achieve this.
But I feel here you need [stop filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html#analysis-stop-tokenfilter) which removes english stop words like `or` and `of`.